# API REST SoapUI POST - BOSE Speaker API

Tags: api, rest, post, http-post

OK apologies, I have never used REST and i'm struggling to get to grips with an API.

So i'm using soapui to process the requests. I can run GET fine as it's just returning data, but I cannot work out how to post.

for example:

```
http://10.0.1.75:8090/info
```

Returns all info about the device.

So to control the device I need to send this:

```
http://10.0.1.75:8090/key

<key state="press" sender="Gabbo">$KEY_VALUE</key>
<key state="release" sender="Gabbo">$KEY_VALUE</key>
```

This seems so simple I must be missing something but I cannot see how to post these parameters in soapui? Once i've worked out one I can write the whole API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This example should answer your question:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="postVolume(0)">Volume 00</button>
    <button onclick="postVolume(10)">Volume 10</button>
    <button onclick="postVolume(20)">Volume 20</button>
    <button onclick="postVolume(30)">Volume 30</button>
    <button onclick="postVolume(40)">Volume 40</button>

    <script>
    function postVolume(volume) {
        var xml = '' + 
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>" +
            "<volume>" + volume + "</volume>";

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://10.0.1.75:8090/volume",true);
        xmlhttp.send(xml);
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this will help you :-)